# Java try/catch - finally usefulness

Tags: java, try-catch

I never use it so I'm wondering about the usefulness of the finally block.

What's the difference between

```
try {
    // A
} catch(...) {
    // B
} finally {
    // C
}
```

and

```
try {
    // A
} catch(...) {
    // B
}
// C
```

In both cases :

if no exceptions -> A,C

if exceptions -> A,B,C

Comment: [Read This...](https://www.javatpoint.com/finally-block-in-exception-handling#:~:text=Java%20finally%20block%20is%20a,the%20exception%20occurs%20or%20not.).

Answer (score 1):

There will be a difference if A throws an exception not caught in `catch` or if the catch block throws an exception.

Answer (score -2):

Can be used to close/free resource after exception has occurred.
Example java function bellow.

```
public static ArrayList foo(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    ArrayList results = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {   
        // create a query, perform the query and
        // process the results
    } finally {
        try {
             rs.close();
        } catch(SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        try {
            ps.close();
       } catch(SQLException ex) {
           throw new RuntimeException(ex);
       }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: ever heard of try-with-resources?

Comment: couldn't get appropriate term to use, I meant things like I/O tasks

Comment: Use try-with-resources. Btw, your code is broken. ps.close() is never called, when rs.close() throws an exception.